# Spring Data MongoDB @Transactional isn't working?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have below maven dependency & configuration set up

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class MongoConfig {

    @Bean
    MongoTransactionManager transactionManager(MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory) {
        return new MongoTransactionManager(mongoDbFactory);
    }
}
```

**Updated**: I've taken the suggested solution to create a bean with `@Transactional`, and have it injected into my test class. Below is the service bean I created:

```
@Service
@Transactional
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MongoTransactionService {

    private final UserRepo userRepo;

    public void boundToFail() throws RuntimeException {
        userRepo.save(User.builder().id("1").build());
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

}
```

and test class where I inject a bean of `MongoTransactionService`:

```
@DataMongoTest(excludeAutoConfiguration = EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class,
        includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = MongoTransactionService.class))
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class MongoTransactionServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    UserRepo userRepo;

    @Autowired
    MongoTransactionService mongoTransactionService;

    @Test
    void testTransactional() {
        try {
            mongoTransactionService.boundToFail();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // do something
        }
        val user = userRepo.findById("1").orElse(null);
        assertThat(user).isNull();
    }

}
```

I am expecting a call to `boundToFail()`, which throws a RuntimeException, would roll back the saved user, but the user still gets persisted in the database after the call.

Comment: Please have a look at the transaction management section for tests in the reference documentation. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-tx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that `@DataMongoTest` doesn't activate the auto-configuration for MongoDB transactions. I've filed [a ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/20182) with Spring Boot to fix that. In the mean time, you can get this to work by adding

```
@ImportAutoConfiguration(TransactionAutoConfiguration.class)
```

to your test class.

Note that using MongoDB transactions requires a replica set database setup. If that's not given the creation of a transaction will fail and your test case will capture that exception and the test will still succeed. The data will not be inserted but that's not due to the `RuntimeException` being thrown but the transaction not being started in the first place.

The question previously presented a slightly different code arrangement that suffered from other problems. For reference, here's the previous answer:

`@Transactional` needs to live on *public* methods of a separate Spring bean as the transactional logic is implemented by wrapping the target object with a proxy that contains an interceptor interacting with the transaction infrastructure.

You example suffers from two problems:

1. The test itself is not a Spring bean. I.e. there's no transactional behavior added to `boundToFail(…)`. `@Transactional` can be used on JUnit test methods but that's controlling the transactional behavior of the test. Most prominently, to roll back the transaction to make sure changes to the data store made in the test do not affect other tests. See [this section](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-tx) of the reference documentation.
2. Even if there was transactional logic applied to `boundToFail(…)`, a local method call to the method would never trigger it as it doesn't pass the proxy that's applying it. See more on that in [the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-annotations).

The solution to your problem is to create a separate Spring bean that carries the `@Transactional` annotation, get that injected into your test case and call the method from the test.